# Don't jump on search and replace

Tags: search, autocmd, replace

How do I get my cursor to not move to the last thing it replaced after a search and replace. No `<C-o>` or extra key presses. Is there some `autocmd` magic I can setup to listen on any `substitute` execution and perform a `<C-o>` automatically after it completes?

If you're curious about further details, it's really for this bread-and-butter mapping, search and replace word under cursor for the whole file, honoring case. I type the binding then start typing the replacement:

```
nnoremap <leader>sr :%s/<c-r><c-w>//gI<left><left><left>
```

and the neovim feature to animate the search and replace:

```
if has("nvim")
    set inccommand=nosplit " No preview window
endif
```

Comment: It is highly recommended not to set gdefault, as it confuses the intuitive meaning of flags and can interfere with plugins which aren’t expecting it/haven’t coded defensively for it.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Good point, updated my vimrc and this question.

Comment: add a `''` after substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that you can prepare a series of commands separated by |.

The solution I'm happy with is:

```
if has("nvim")
  set inccommand=nosplit " Remove horizontal split that shows a preview of whats changing
endif
" E means edit with confirms, e is no confirm. 
" Second letter is source: w is word under cursor, y is yanked text.
" Even with very no magic (\V) modifier, still need to escape / and \ with \
" The \< and \> means don't do a raw string replace but a word replace
" so if you want to replace someVar, it won't touch vars name someVarOther
" edit word in whole file
nnoremap <leader>ew :%s/\V\<<c-r><c-w>\>//gI \|normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left>
" Edit confirm word in whole file
nnoremap <leader>Ew :,$s/\V\<<c-r><c-w>\>//gIc \|1,''-&&<c-left><left><left><left><left><left>
" edit word under cursor within the visual lines
" gv selects the last vis selection (line, block or select)
vnoremap <leader>ew <Esc>yiwgv:s/\V\<<c-r>"\>//gI \| normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left>
" Visually selected text in file
" If mode is visual line mode, edit the prev yank acros the vis lines, else across the whole file
" see :help escape()
vnoremap <expr> <leader>ey mode() ==# "V" ? 
      \ ":s/\\V<c-r><c-r>=escape(@\", '/\\')<cr>//gI \| normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left>"
      \: "y:%s/\\V<c-r><c-r>=escape(@\", '/\\')<cr>//gI \| normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left>"

nnoremap <leader>ey :%s/\V<c-r>=escape(@", '/\\')<cr>//gI <bar> normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left>
nnoremap <leader>Ey :%s/\V<c-r>=escape(@", '/\\')<cr>//gIc <bar> normal <c-o><c-left><c-left><c-left><left><left><left><left><left>
```